# Mac terminal (lost password)

Tags: macos

Can't use terminal on my Imac because a password is required after entering a command.

What now ?

Need help  . . .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can, try resetting the password via Apple or asking Apple support - they often can help with these issues.

Answer (score 0):

".AppleSetupDone"

Put that into google for older Macs running "OS X"

For newer macs running "MacOS" hold Option+R to enter recovery mode, launch terminal from the menubar, and type resetpassword into terminal.

If neither works, contact Apple support!